# Insert template after a element

Tags: angularjs

I have a template that looks like this,

```
<table>
  <tr "ng-repeat" => "row in moviesRows">
    <td "ng-repeat" => "movie in row>
      {{ movie.title }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Which creates a html structure like this,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

My goal is to when a user clicks on a TD element that a template is inserted at the end of the row. Resulting in something like this,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td> < TD clicked
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="container_template>
    <td ui-view="something">Template info etc.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Would something like this be possible using angularJS or perhaps even Javascript?

Comment: There are ways to accomplish the effect you are wanting to achieve, for example using `ng-if` to conditionally add or remove DOM elements.  However, the result you posted here isn't valid HTML, and wouldn't render the way you expect.  `<table><div></div></table>` isn't valid, and most browsers would move the `<div></div>` group outside the table, causing it to render in unexpected locations.

Comment: You are correct about the code not being viable HTML. Do you think it is possible to add another table row, and then insert the view inside the td?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by adding this piece of code after each row

```
<tr class="container_template>
  <td ui-view="something">Template info etc.</td>
</tr>
```

and, use a ngShow to make it visible or not.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td ngclick="models[0] = !models[0]">Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="container_template ngshow="models[0]">
    <td ui-view="something">Template info etc.</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td ngclick="models[1] = !models[1]">Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="container_template ngshow="models[1]">
    <td ui-view="something">Template info etc.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td ngclick="models[2] = !models[2]">Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="container_template ngshow="models[2]">
    <td ui-view="something">Template info etc.</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="row in moviesRows">
    <td ng-repeat="movie in row" ng-click"models[row.$index] = !models[row.$index]">
      {{ movie.title }}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="container_template ng-show="models[row.$index]" ng-repeat-end>
    <td ui-view="something">Template info etc.</td>
  </tr>   
</table>
```